# Custom count_nonzero function for numpy versions below 1.6

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

i coded a little program and i am currently in the process of making it work on different operating systems. My program heavily relies on the function **count_nonzero** introduced with numpy version 1.6 .

My primary workstation is Debian Linux with numpy (ver. 1.6.2) and scipy (ver. 0.11).
However on windows the setup could involve older numpy version below 1.6, where the **count_nonzero** command isn't available. Therefore i am in need of a custom **count_nonzero** function which works on systems with older numpy versions.

> def count_nonzero(self,array):
>
> ```
>     if hasattr(numpy,'count_nonzero'):
>         return numpy.count_nonzero(array)
>     elif hasattr(scipy,'count_nonzero'):
>         return scipy.count_nonzero(array)
>     else:
>         # Alternative ?
> ```

How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
(array != 0).sum()
```

Comment: thanks! It works and it is even slightly faster than my solution (0.08 sec to 0.01).

Answer (score 0):

Ahh, 
okay i found a solution, but i'm open to smarter alternatives :)

```
numpy.size(array[array!=0])
```